# Mistake in my Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

> Expand the function $$f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2(z-2)}$$ into a Laurent series which converges on a region $0<|z|<R$, and determine the greatest possible value of $R$.

We can see that we need a Laurent Series about the point $z=0$.

What I tried was \begin{align}\frac{1}{z^2(z-2)} &= \frac{1}{z^3 -2z^2} \\ &= \frac{1}{z^3} \bigg[ \frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{z}}\bigg] \\ &= \frac{1}{z^3} \sum_{n=0}^\infty\bigg( \frac{2}{z}\bigg)^n \\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{z^{n+3}}\end{align}

When I use the ratio test, I get \begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg| \frac{2^{n+1} \cdot z^{n}}{z^{n+1}\cdot2^n}\bigg| &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg|\frac{2}{z}\bigg| \\ &=\bigg|\frac{2}{z}\bigg| \end{align}
Now for the radius of convergence, we require $$\bigg|\frac{2}{z}\bigg| <1$$

This does not seem to be correct.

When I use WolframAlpha, I get a completely different (negative) Laurent Series with radius of convergence $|z| < 2$, which makes a lot more sense.

Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT: HERE IS MY RE-ATTEMPT**

I retried it using the following

\begin{align}f(z) &= \frac{1}{z^2}\cdot \frac{1}{z-2} \\ &= \frac{1}{z^2} \cdot \frac{-1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{z}{2}} \\ &= \frac{1}{z^2} \cdot \frac{-1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg( \frac{z}{2} \bigg)^n \\ &= - \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n-2}}{2^{n+1}}\end{align}

This seems to have radius of convergence $|z|<2$. Is this correct??

Comment: You determined the Laurent series that converges in the region $2 < \lvert z\rvert < +\infty$. To get the Laurent series converging for $0 < \lvert z\rvert < 2$, you need to expand $\frac{1}{z-2} = -\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1 - \frac{z}{2}}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer - See my edit that I posted just now with my reattempt :). Is there a way that I can prevent making this mistake in the future? i.e is there anything that I can look out for to prevent me using the "wrong manipulation" the first time around?

Comment: Fun timing ;) Yes, your new attempt is correct. But it would be more standard to write it as $$-\sum_{n = -2}^\infty \frac{z^n}{2^{n+3}}.$$

Comment: Not sure if there's a fool-proof way to avoid such mistakes. But I would expect that next time [if a next time comes] you will know exactly what you did wrong (very soon, you will know it as soon as you write the analogue of $\dfrac{1}{1-\frac{2}{z}}$), and then finding the correct way is typically not hard.

Comment: @DanielFischer - I just got it! :D. If I need the series where it converges for $r< |z| < \infty$, i require my "$z$-term" of my Laurent series in the denominator. If I require the $|z|<r$ series, I require my Laurent series with the "$z$-term" in the numerator. The correct manipulation required to get that is quite obvious then :). Thank you! :)

Comment: Yes, basically. But if you have more singularities, say on the circles $\lvert z\rvert = r_k,\, 1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$ with $r_k < r_{k+1}$ and you want the Laurent series converging for $r_k < \lvert z\rvert < r_{k+1}$, then it's not quite as obvious maybe. It's the same principle, however, as long as you deal with structurally simple functions. For every term you need to see whether you need to expand on a disk $\lvert z\rvert < r$ ($z$ in the numerator) or on the complement of a disk ($\lvert z\rvert > r$, then $z$ goes in the denominator).